# New 1080p monitor slightly blurry

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, resolution, displayport

I have a Lubuntu 17.10 system, running with an AMD Radeon HD 7770 graphics card, which I've used with a 1680x1050 Samsung monitor via DVI for nearly 10 years with no problems.

I have recently bought a new monitor, a Viewsonic XG2401. I have attached it to the graphics card using DisplayPort (the cable came with the monitor), leaving the old monitor untouched, and set the new monitor as the primary with a 1920x1080 resolution.

However, I find that the new monitor is very slightly blurry. The old one works just as well as before, but I'm finding it hard to read on the new one. I've increased the sharpness setting of the monitor to the max, which has helped a bit, but still the image looks a bit blurred.

Anything I can do to fix the sharpness on the new monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Check the driver settings for overscan. On Windows at least, it has been my experience in the past that AMD drivers will enable overscan scaling by default for HDMI (e.g. anything other than VGA & DVI).

Comment: `xrandr` reports for the monitor: underscan vborder: 0, underscan hborder: 0, underscan: off (supported: off, on, auto). Is this correct?

Comment: I frankly do not use ubuntu except as a VM. That sounds like it is disabled, but I know it may be on a per-output basis and you may need to target an interface. Might look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/508358/ and https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2357579 for ideas regarding specifics

Comment: look especially at any potential transforms, this is another word for "resample" or "resize" if the factor is not 1.0

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of blurriness that you are experiencing, but the issue I most frequently encounter is solved by separating the monitor's display cable from the power cable.

For some reason, when display cables run next to power cables for a period of time, it causes what looks like a huge smudge on all the text.